# Input field not changing its width

Tags: html, css, input

I have a input field

```
  .form-field {
   width: 500px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: var(--input-color);
    border: 3px solid var(--input-border);
    background: var(--input-background);
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
  }
```

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="form-label"">something</span>
        <input class="form-field" type="text" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-field" type="text" placeholder="40%">
        <span class="form-label">something</span>
    </div>
```

Tried changing the width, did not work, I dont know any other ways to do it ;( so I am stuck here

Comment: Have you used your browsers devtools inspect facility to see exactly what css is being applied and where it is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have a double " at your first "form-label". But I don't think that will be impacting the width of your form fields. I would guess there is another css class in your code that is affecting the width of the inputs. Check out the snippet below, you can change the width at the top of the CSS and the field will change.

```css
<style>  
   .form-field {
     width: 200px;
     display: block;
     padding: 8px 16px;
     line-height: 25px;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 500;
     font-family: inherit;
     border-radius: 6px;
     color: var(--input-color);
     border: 3px solid var(--input-border);
     background: var(--input-background);
     transition: border 0.3s ease;
   }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <span class="form-label">something</span>
        <input class="form-field" type="text" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-field" type="text" placeholder="40%">
        <span class="form-label">something</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, heres my full code! https://pastebin.com/Zvr9JsMR (CSS), can you help me :)

Comment: body .form-group {
    max-width: 360px;
  } This is declaring the maximum width that the elements can be. If you change this, you can change the width of the form-field.

Comment: Hi, Thank you!, I did not realize it since I kinda copied it from codepen